# How can I disable "TLS InsecureSkipVerify may be true" error

Tags: go, lint, gosec

I have a code like this:

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(),
    }
}
```

When I run `golangci-lint run` it recognizes the `nolint` directive and ignores that error, but when Sonarqube runs it keeps failing with a message "TLS InsecureSkipVerify may be true"

This issue https://github.com/securego/gosec/issues/278 talks about using `#nosec` in the comment to disable that error.
Here it talks about using it in specific parts of the statement https://github.com/securego/gosec/issues/278#issuecomment-745209803

So I've tried:

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        // NOSONAR #nosec 
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(),
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(), // NOSONAR #nosec 
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(),
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(), /* #nosec */
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        /* #nosec */ InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(), /* #nosec */
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        /* #nosec */ InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure() /* #nosec */, /* #nosec */
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        /* #nosec */ InsecureSkipVerify: /* #nosec */ cfg.GetRedisInsecure() /* #nosec */, /* #nosec */
    }
}
```

And

```
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() {
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        //nolint:gosec // NOSONAR #nosec need insecure TLS option for testing and development
        /* #nosec */ InsecureSkipVerify /* #nosec */ :/* #nosec */ cfg.GetRedisInsecure(), /* #nosec */
    }
}
```

I have open this issue in the gosec project https://github.com/securego/gosec/issues/780

What else can I do to ignore this in gosec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@rodolfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3578294/rodolfo) has suggested, I reproduce the solution mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/securego/gosec/issues/780#issuecomment-1043098087) as it might help someone else.

Apparently using `// #nosec G402`  on the same line as the `if` statement fixes the problem:

```golang
if cfg.GetRedisTLS() { // #nosec G402
    clientOpts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        InsecureSkipVerify: cfg.GetRedisInsecure(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an if statement, you can make a command block

```
        { // #nosec G402
            clientOpts.tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
                RootCAs:            or.certificates,
                InsecureSkipVerify: or.insecure,
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `#nosec G402` comment on the line where the warning is reported worked for me.

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true, // #nosec G402
    },
}
```

As mentionned in the gosec project [README](https://github.com/securego/gosec?tab=readme-ov-file#annotating-code).